# UWP - save item

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

in XAML i created button and when i click on the button then background will be changed to red color(because i set it) but if i close my application and then again start application so background is not red. What i need to do is keep background there like before(when i clicked on button) so have red background if i again start application. Your help will be for me very important. Thank you experts. Btw this is code for button now: :).

```
    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        background.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

Comment: Just store it in the App settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/app-settings-and-data

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the selected color; or save somwething some you can determine what color it has to be. In the constructor or your page read this value and set the right color.

you can use localsettings to save this.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] = "Red";
```

for example.

In the constructor:

```
if ( ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] == "Red") 
{
background.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

full sample:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            if ((string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] == "Red")
                LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] = "Red";
            LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
```

Comment: Fully agree.. but dont have enough context to advice something better or need to define something as enum in example. So you have completly valid point

Comment: Man thank you for your anser but it will be very nice if you can tell me more.

Comment: i wrote your example in the constructor to my app excatly the same but it is not working.

Comment: this worked for me: public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            if ((string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] == "Red")
                LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["BGColor"] = "Red";
            LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

Comment: here is working sample: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApdKhb5zPLrRy5B7sEDVtjKqCX_RKg

Comment: Ok i have there error but right now it is working. Thank you man :)))